# Editing "First Posts" outside of review page

Tags: discussion

I noticed that when I edit a user's first question after selecting it from the "Questions" page I do not get credit for reviewing a "First Post" the way that I would if had edited the same question on the review page. Is that intended? Does anyone think you should get credit either way since it would be encouraging the same action?

Comment: That's most likely by design; review has its own actions that are limited to 20 per day. Editing just like that is a different action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the review actions need to be done via the reviews pane to count towards the total. If you do it off-page, you aren't reviewing - you're just editing.

Comment: And yet if you edit a post out of the review queue, but get the link to that post's entry in the review queue the "I'm done" button will be enabled, and you can click it without performing additional actions and get credit.