# Showing Stack Overflow's reputation for OP here on Meta

Tags: feature-request, design

On all meta sites except this one, the meta reputation is the same as on the main site.

However being the "super meta" site, reputation here is independent. All good.

Since many times the questions here are closely related to the asker's profile on the main site and/or his reputation there seeing the reputation on the main site is a very common action.

For example in [this question here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153313/editing-first-posts-outside-of-review-page) I want to know the OP reputation on the main site to know whether he means full edits, or suggested edits.

Currently to do this I have to go to the OP [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/190533/woz), and look for his Stack Overflow account data in there. Not the end of the world, but would be lot better if we got such thing:

[image]

Design might need a little tweak, maybe give bit more height to the whole box but hope you can see the point.

Users without account on Stack Overflow will have only one line of course.

Comment: This'll be less of an issue when/if we finally switch to Meta Stack Exchange because MSO will be a normal meta, so you'll only see their SO rep.

Comment: That's would be nice. I'm tried of talking to 50k SO users like they were newcomers just because they have 101 rep here on Meta. (Since MSO is the meta site for all SE, maybe we could display combined SE reputation instead of pure SO reputation?)

Comment: @Ben sure, but this might take years. :/

Comment: @Dennis interesting idea, maybe show the user's combined flair? Hmm...

Comment: Obligatory link: [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: given that currently this site serves as network wide meta, it would make more sense to show "network wide" rep, the value like one shown in chat or in combined flair

Comment: Why not just get rid of the badges, and show SO rep there instead? Like `2,387 / 292`? I don't think anyone cares about the badges a poster has, and I don't think it'd be that hard to do as it wouldn't  require resizing the template. Also, I'd like to see someone's MSO rep separate from their SO rep, so don't like the idea of showing a combined reputation score as long as MSO represents both StackExchange in general and SO

Comment: @PopularDemand "few months" already passed since February without any hint of anything that is being cooked.

Comment: @Gnat that's what Ben suggested above in the first comment but yeah, good idea as well. Whatever is more simple to implement.

Comment: @Rachel that would be too radical change in my opinion. Too used to see the badges, don't want to see them go away.

Comment: Showing network-wide rep is fine, so long as SO rep is also showed - I know that might start to make things too cumbersome, but I think seeing SO rep would be most valuable.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know, but that's still the most recent news about the split.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think the first comment can read as after split, when there will be SO-specific meta, your request will be done automagically - that's why I specifically asked for network-wide rep for *now* (and most likely, for future _network-wide-only_ meta.SE) - just to make sure it won't somehow get lost in waiting _6-to-8-weeks_ for split to happen.

Answer (score 14):

My main concern with adding this would be that it feels like a power user feature being special-cased into Meta, and I'm not sure offhand that the potential benefits necessarily justify doing that.

Still, it's hard to say that it *wouldn't* be useful without having it to play around with, so (perhaps unsurprisingly) I went ahead and [made a userscript](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-mse-reps.user.js) that will allow me to do just that on Meta:

[image: usercards displaying additional information]

<s>If the user has an accept rate, it's what's displayed by default, and</s>* Clicking the icon on the right toggles between the various modes. You'll note from the screenshot that for the network-wide reputation count, it also displays a diamond if the user is a moderator elsewhere on the network.

<sup>*Now that accept rate is [being removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654), this will no longer be true. I've registered an API key and updated the script to use it when making requests, so I'd recommend updating to the latest version for anyone who installed the script prior to this change.</sup>

Of course, now that MSO has become MSE, the Stack Overflow aspect of the script ceased to be useful. I've now updated it accordingly to just show the network reputation (and mod status):

[image: MSE version of the combined reputation]

Answer (score 12):

There is a lot of information about a user that might be useful when answering meta questions. Not only the SO reputation, but the reputation of any SE site or even the network-wide reputation would be useful. This is not the SO meta alone, it is also the meta site for all network-wide issues.

Knowing that a user is a moderator of some site would be useful in some cases, there's an old feature request for that. But often you want to take a look at specific posts, and need to go via the profile anyway.

This display would save one single click in some instances, I don't think this is enough to justify making this change. I'm all for eliminating the accept rate and putting something useful there, but I don't think the SO rep is that important. If it would be implemented at all, the network-wide reputation would be more useful in my opinion.

Comment: One solution to your second paragraph would be a network meta, and make every mod automatically a mod on meta.se

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Not sure if having 300 mods on one site is a good idea. I think an indication would be nice, but actual moderator powers for every mod are not necessary.

Comment: Maybe a hollow diamond ♢ (U+2662) ?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: Area 51 uses grey diamonds to indicate mod status on a certain number of sites, and a blue diamond for Area 51 mod status. Hollow diamond is a better idea though.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll leave it to the hands of the dev team if and when they'll consider such change. :)